# NodeJS - HTTPS/HTTP Proxy Server Setup

Tags: node.js, http, https, proxy

I'm currently trying to setup an HTTP/HTTPS proxy server using NodeJS. Using the example of this [gist](https://gist.github.com/nadeeshacabral/6863947), this is what I have.

```
var fs = require('fs'),
  http = require('http'),
  https = require('https'),
  httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

var isHttps = true; // do you want a https proxy?

var options = {
  https: {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/home/ubuntu/key.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/home/ubuntu/crt.crt')
  }
};

// this is the target server
var proxy = new httpProxy.HttpProxy({
  target: {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 11612
  }
});

if (isHttps)
  https.createServer(options.https, function(req, res) {
    console.log('Proxying https request at %s', new Date());
    proxy.proxyRequest(req, res);
  }).listen(443, function(err) {
    if (err)
      console.log('Error serving https proxy request: %s', req);

    console.log('Created https proxy. Forwarding requests from %s to %s:%s', '443', proxy.target.host, proxy.target.port);
  });
else
  http.createServer(options.https, function(req, res) {
    console.log('Proxying http request at %s', new Date());
    console.log(req);
    proxy.proxyRequest(req, res);
  }).listen(80, function(err) {
    if (err)
      console.log('Error serving http proxy request: %s', req);

    console.log('Created http proxy. Forwarding requests from %s to %s:%s', '80', proxy.target.host, proxy.target.port);
  });
```

Issue is, when I run it on my Ubuntu server, this is the error I'm getting. Kinda lost.

```
/home/ubuntu/prox.js:16
var proxy = new httpProxy.HttpProxy({
            ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/prox.js:16:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
17 Jan 23:18:34 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: `httpProxy` doesn't have a property called `HttpProxy`.  What does it have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the following, might help, this is from their git hub page.

```
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer(options);
```